# Stretch Tkinter Rectangle

Tags: python, python-2.7, canvas, tkinter

I know you can change a tkinter object by using self.canvas.itemconfig(). But you need to know the attribute name to alter it. I would like to stretch a rectangle horizontally, but the only documentation I can find for create_rectangle called the coordinates 'Rectangle bounding box'. So does anyone know what each one is actually called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the coordinates of a `Tkinter.Canvas` object, use the `Canvas.coords` function (documentation here).

For example:

```
self.canvas.coords(tagOrID, x0, y0, x1, y1)
```

Where tagOrID is the internal Canvas tag or ID of the rectangle, and x0, y0, x1, and y1 are the new coordinates of the rectangle.

Comment: As a side note, in create_rectangle, the coordinates you supply are "positional" arguments, which are non-keyword arguments.  That means you don't need to know the attribute name, you just supply the value (i.e. `canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1)`)